# Membership bulk email software

Tags: asp.net

We have a Microsoft web stack web site, we have a members database.

We want to start doing mass-emails to our (opted in) membership.

I don't *particularly* want to re-invent the wheel with a system for having a web form submit and then mass send emails looping through thousands of records without timing out and overloading the server...

I guess I'm looking for something like Mailman, that can run on a windows (ASP/ASP.NET + SQL Server) backend and do the work for me, with suitable APIs to manage the subscriber list and send emails to that list.

Suggestions please?

Comment: have you found a solution that worked for you?  I'm interested in what kind of solution you went with, what software or services?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with acrosman, third parties that host email lists are a good way to go.  A very reliable site I've found for mass emailing is http://mailing-list-services.com/.  They do a good job to make sure their servers are never black listed or marked as spam. I've used them a few times, their website design blows, but their service is awsome.  The Lyris Listmanager software they use has a pretty extensive API.

Answer (score 1):

[Advanced Intellect](http://www.advancedintellect.com/productlist.aspx) has some great tools, like aspNetEmail and ListNanny.

Answer (score 1):

MaxBulkMailer might be a solution for you?  The organisation I work for uses it to connect to www.authsmtp.com which gives us credits for a certain number of e-mails that we can send per month.  You can import a spreadsheet of your mailing list or tap straight into a SQL server and pull the names and addresses.  Available for Mac and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

(not a sales pitch)
[my company](http://www.acsysinteractive.com) offers [mail manager](http://www.acsysinteractive.com/product/default.aspx), but it's a hosted service. It has a full API though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out how [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) does this

Answer (score 0):

Unless your running a business that specializes in email, I'd suggest you find a hosted solution.  There are 100's of little issues that come up when you run your own service over time.  A hosted solution can save you lots of time and effort (and therefore money).